# double to long conversion of a big value does not produce the same value

Tags: java

```
double d = 1000000000138719341D;
System.out.print(Double.valueOf(d).longValue());
```

The printed result is

```
1000000000138719360
```

Why is it different? And how do I get the correct result?

Comment: What is the "correct" result?

Comment: the correct value should be 1000000000138719341

Comment: A `double` can only reliably hold 15-16 significant digits. 
 http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=1000000000138719341&floattype=double

Comment: @ajb  thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **double**: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
>   discussion, but is specified in the [Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)
>   section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values,
>   this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above,
>   **this data type should never be used for precise values**, such as
>   currency.

Answer (score 1):

you need  `java.math.BigDecimal` class